# Autohotkey: Script to auto indent the hotstring in next line

Tags: autohotkey, indentation

I made a Autohotkey script, that expands some useful html tags like when you type  it automatically expands it to  and creates a new line with one tab space and places cursor there in between as below (like a code editor)

```
<div>

</div>
```

This code is like

```
:*:<div>::<div>`n`t`n</div>{up}
```

But when I have typed the same code after one tab space it must readjust the closing tag with the tab spaces present before the opening tag. Like the tags inside

```
<div>
     <div>

     </div>
<div>
```

For one tab, the code looks like,

```
:*:<div>::<div>`n`t`t`n`t</div>{up}
```

I don't know how to combine the above two codes such that whatever the tab spaces are the closing tags should be placed at the same indent as their opening tags

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to have one code that will insert the opening and closing tags but also preserve and maintain the indentation scheme. In my solution below, it copies everything before the cursor on the current line and pastes it at the beginning of each line. I also made it a function so that it can be reused for as many tags as you wish, as shown with the few extra I added as examples.

**Edit:** Modified code based on comments below

```
:*:<div>::
:*:<html>::
:*:<title>::
:*:<body>::
f_TagReplace( SubStr( A_ThisHotkey , 4 ) , "</" . SubStr( A_ThisHotkey , 5 ))
Return

:*:{::
f_TagReplace( "{{}" , "{}}" )
Return

f_TagReplace( sTag , sTagEnd )
{
    Clipboard := ""
    Send , +{home}^c
    ClipWait , 0.2
    Send , ^v%sTag%`n^v`t`n^v%sTagEnd%{up}{end}
}
```

---

*(Original code for reference)*

```
:*:<div>::
:*:<html>::
:*:<title>::
:*:<body>::
f_TagReplace( SubStr( A_ThisHotkey , 4 ))
Return

f_TagReplace( sTag )
{
    sTagEnd := "</" . SubStr( sTag , 2 )
    Clipboard := ""
    Send , +{home}^c
    ClipWait , 0.2
    Send , ^v%sTag%`n^v`t`n^v%sTagEnd%{up}
}
```

Comment: I want to extend the same logic to auto-complete opening braces '{' with closing braces '}' at exact indents, but I'm unable to do it, can you explain it also..

Comment: What do you mean by "at exact indents"? That the closing `}` is at the same indentation level as the opening `{`?

Comment: Yes closing bracket at the same indentation level as the opening bracket

Comment: Understood. Please see the updated code. Note that you may wish to make this context-sensitive or use a special key combination so that you can use `{` normally if needed.

Comment: That's kind of you to say. However, I think with a bit more experience you'll see my coding is low amatuer at best.

Answer (score 0):

Had someone on the AHK subreddit ask about this post, so I created a v2 version that's a bit more flexible and reliable.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey 2.0+                                       ; ALWAYS have a version requiement

make_html_hotstrings()                                          ; Generates the initial hotstrings

make_html_hotstrings() {
    tag_list := ['html', 'head', 'title', 'body', 'p', 'div'    ; Array of tags you want hotstrings made of
                ,'span', 'em', 'strong', 'ol', 'ul', 'li']
    
    for _, tag in tag_list                                      ; Loop through list
        Hotstring(':*?b0:<' tag '>', close_tag.Bind(tag))       ; Create each hotstring and on fire, call close_tag(tag)
}

close_tag(tag, *) {
    bak := ClipboardAll()                                       ; Backup the current clipboard so data isn't lost
    A_Clipboard := ''                                           ; Clear clipboard
    SendInput('+{Home 2}')                                      ; Hilight the whole string
    Sleep(1)
    SendInput('^c')                                             ; Copy text to clipboard
    If !ClipWait(1,1)                                           ; Wait up to 1 second for text to show up
        return (A_Clipboard := bak)                             ; If not, restore clipboard and stop thread

    if RegExMatch(A_Clipboard, "^([ |\t]+)", &m)                ; If text found, check for indentation and save it
        ind := m[1]                                             ; Set indent to the indentation found
    else ind := ''                                              ; Else indent is empty
    A_Clipboard := ind '<' tag '>'                              ; Build the string and put it on the clipboard
        . '`n' ind
        . '`n' ind '</' tag '>'
    
    SendInput('^v')                                             ; Paste end product
    Loop 20                                                     ; Wait up to 1 second for clipboard to not be in use
        Sleep(50)
    until !DllCall('GetOpenClipboardWindow')                    ; Break when clipboard isn't in use
    SendInput("{Up 2}")                                         ; Cursor up to the initial tag
    A_Clipboard := bak                                          ; And restore original clipboard
}
```